# C++ not recognizing spaces

Tags: c++

I am a relative novice to programming in general and i am having trouble with this piece of code.

```
cout << "what would you like to have inside that?" << endl;
cout << "please enter a sentance" << endl; 
cin.sync();
cin >> time[d];

cout << "Is this what you wrote?" << endl;
cout << time[d]<< endl;

system("pause");
```

it doesn't go past the the space and only outputs before it.

Comment: What do you mean ***doesn't go past the space***?

Comment: `getline(std::cin, time[d])`.  As far as `>>` is concerned, any whitespace is a delimiter.

Comment: Please don't use `sync()` if you don't know what it does. Also, formatted input is delimited by whitespace.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting input from user using cin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184125/getting-input-from-user-using-cin)

Answer (score 4):

`std::cin` considers all whitespace (spaces, newlines, tabs, etc.) to be "delimeters" between separate inputs. There are ways to change the delimeter, but you're probably better served by [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/) which defaults to newline as the delimeter (though you can optionally specify a different one).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for std::getline, as std::cin will treat any whitespace as a delimiter. Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::string> time(1);
  size_t d = 0;

  std::cout << "What would you like to have inside of that?" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Please enter a sentence: ";
  std::getline(std::cin, time[d]);

  std::cout << "Is this what you wrote?" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "[" << time[d] << "]" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead using `cin` to take input `time[d]`, try using `getline`. You may modify your code as below -

```
 cout << "Please enter a sentence: ";
 std::getline(std::cin, time[d], delim);
```

Now it takes `time[d]` as string until the delimitation character `delim` is found. The delimitation character can be like `\t`, `\n`, etc.

If you don't specify delimitation character, it takes `\n` as default delimiter.